# When trying to upgrade Kerberos development libraries, why do I get an "unmet dependencies" error?

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates

When I'm upgrading, get this error and can't install anything else

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 is installed
                 Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 is installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 is installed
                 Depends: libgssrpc4 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 is installed
                 Depends: libkadm5srv-mit8 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 is installed
                 Depends: libkadm5clnt-mit8 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried to run  `apt-get install -f` but I still get the unmet dependencies error.

this is the `apt-cache policy` output :
(i couldn't post it to much hyper links so i pastebin it)

[apt-cache policy output](http://pastebin.com/zEACHge2)

Comment: Please edit your post to show the output of `apt-cache policy`

Comment: It looks like the packages that are installed are newer than the ones that are being requested.

Comment: You use repositories from lucid, oneiric and precise. That's probably what's causing your problem. Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @jP_wanN  im using  12.04

Comment: I think you have to clean up your repositories with ppa-purge and then retry it again. First, to see if the problem is really caused by your repos, try to install the `krb5-multidev` package on a ubuntu live system after once reloading the software lists with `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @jP_wanN cant get terminal in try ubuntu ...

Comment: Why? Normally you can access it with Ctrl+Alt+T and over the dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fixed it:

I went to the **Synaptic** package manager in order to fix the broken package. Click on Edit → Fix Broken packages.

Answer (score 3):

[A security update for Kerberos packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/krb5/1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3) was issued on July 31, 2012, to fix a security vulnerability. This bumped the Ubuntu version numbers from `ubuntu0.2` to `ubuntu0.3`.

It's possible (but rare) that for a while, the `libkrb5-dev`/`krb5-multidev` packages were not updated, and thus had the old dependencies of `ubuntu0.2` which was causing your problem.

In any case, it appears this has now been fixed:

```
$ apt-cache show libkrb5-dev | grep Depends
Depends: krb5-multidev (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3)

$ apt-cache show krb5-multidev | grep Depends
Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3), libk5crypto3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3), libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3), libgssrpc4 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3), libkadm5srv-mit8 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3), libkadm5clnt-mit8 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3), comerr-dev
```

Please try a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install` to try to fix this. If it it doesn't, just remove the `libkrb5-dev` package. From a simulated removal on my dev system, it appears that the CUPS and QT dev packages may also be removed (`libqt3-mt-dev`, `libcups2-dev`). And then install `libkrb5-dev` again.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest attempting to remove the troublesome package before upgrading.

First, make sure removing krb5-multidev won't remove anything that appears to be vital.

```
sudo apt-get remove krb5-multidev --simulate
```

Review the packages under "The following packages will be REMOVED:". If you're not sure whether they are important, feel free to post the list here for us to look over for you.

Assuming nothing looks vital, go ahead and remove krb5-multidev:

```
sudo apt-get remove krb5-multidev
```

Then attempt the upgrade again. Once you've upgraded, you can reinstall krb5-multidev.

**NOTE:** There are probably more elegant methods to solve this problem. This is just an attempt to work around the error and get the upgrade done.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove krb5-multidev --simulate
the output is
 Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkrb5-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Okay, I've got to admit, I'm a bit rusty on this sort of thing. If I were you, I'd try forcing the removal of any krb5 package that's being a problem (e.g. `sudo apt-get remove libkrb5-dev --force`). I would just be careful that no important packages accidentally went out the window with them. HOWEVER, you might want to hold out for a more elegant answer.